# How to assign by reference of object property

Tags: javascript

How to assign object property by reference. My object look like this:

```
obj = {
    level: {
        level: {
           level: {} 
     }
   }
 }
```

My code something like this:

```
var obj = {
    level: {
        level: {
            level: {} 
        }
    }
 };


do {
    var level = obj.level;
} while(Object.keys(level).length != 0);


level = {
    newPro: 'Some value'
}
```

But any change in the last level property.

Expected output:

```
{
    level: {
        level: {
            level: {
                newPro: 'Some value'
            } 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test if the next `level` exist.

If exists, take the value of the `level` as new value for `temp` for a new `while` loop.

If not, assign a new property to the temporary object.

```js
var object = { level: { level: { level: {} } } },
    temp = object;

while (temp.level) {
    temp = temp.level;
}

temp.newPro = 'Some value';

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic of `do-while`

```
while(Object.keys(level).length != 0)
```

is stuck in an infinite loop since `level` is always `obj.level` and never changing.

**You were almost there**, just

- keep a temp object
- assign the value to its property (`newPro`) **rather than assigning the value directly**.

```js
var obj = {
  level: {
    level: {
      level: {}
    }
  }
};
var temp = obj;
while (Object.keys(temp).length > 0) {
  temp = temp.level;
}
temp.newPro = 'Some value'
console.log(obj);
```